# pagination div pages with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

With this script i try show pages inside divs with content, and move each time and the people wants see some page, can click over number page and load, the problem actually it´s when people click over number page, show more of 1 page, and not show the page´s number

**TEST HERE :**

https://jsfiddle.net/2mvek66f/

```
<script>


var total_pages=3;
pg=0;


function gopage(num_page)
{

jQuery(".page"+num_page).fadeIn(1000);

pg=num_page;
}


function init_pages()
{
jQuery(".page"+pg).fadeIn(1000,function(){auto_pages();});
}



function auto_pages()
{
jQuery(".page"+pg).fadeOut(1000,function(){init_pages();});
pg ++;



if(pg>=total_pages)
{
pg=0;
}

}
</script>
```

**HTML CODE WITH PAGES**

```
Pages:



<div class="page0" style="position:relative;width:200px;height:200px;margin:auto;background-color:red;display:none;"></div>
<div class="page1" style="position:relative;width:200px;height:200px;margin:auto;background-color:green;display:none;"></div>
<div class="page2" style="position:relative;width:200px;height:200px;margin:auto;background-color:blue;display:none;"></div>

<script>
init_pages();
</script>

<br>



<span onclick="gopage(0);">1</span>
<span onclick="gopage(1);">2</span>
<span onclick="gopage(2);">3</span>
```

When the people click over links in footer ,"gopage" must load the select div, but actually the problem in many cases, it´s that when click over pagination´s number, show more divs and not selected div

Comment: so you want that when the pagination is clicked the specific div is displayed , and what should happen to the animation?, should it stop once you click on the number in the pagination in footer

Comment: I want go the page selected from pagination and show and befores continue with the other pages and when click in other number from pagination show that pageshow , hide and continue the oter pages before show click page

Comment: Does that last comment even makes sense?

Comment: If you can help me perfect, don´t speak english howewer if you try my language sure i tell you the same and laugh of you, do you want try eh ?